# How do I prepare query parameters before calling the execute function with tokio-postgres in Rust?

Tags: postgresql, rust, types

I have the following code:

```rust
let query = "INSERT INTO users (uuid, pass) VALUES = $1, $2"; 
let statement = db_client.prepare(query).await?
let params = [&user.uuid, &user.pass];
let res = db_client.execute(&statement, params).await?;
```

Although, I am getting the following error: expected reference `&[&dyn ToSql + Sync]`.

I've tried setting the params to type "&[&dyn ToSql + Sync]"

```rust
let statement: &[&dyn ToSql + Sync] = db_client.prepare(query).await?
```

but, no avail.

I've also tried using the macro, to_sql_checked!() on the array... but this does not work either.

Regardless, the following code works:

```rust
let res = db_client.execute(&statement, &[&user.uuid, &user.pass]).await?;
```

What is really the difference here? I believe the code would be better if I was able to preassign the query values before sending them. What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```rust
let query = "INSERT INTO users (uuid, pass) VALUES = $1, $2"; 
let statement = db_client.prepare(query).await?
let params = &[&user.uuid, &user.pass];
let res = db_client.execute(&statement, params).await?;
```

Note the extra borrow in front of the array assigned to `params`.

If it doesn't then you have to ascribe the type of `params` for some reason you did ascribe a type to `statement` instead‽

```rust
let params: &[&dyn ToSql + Sync] = &[&user.uuid, &user.pass];
```